# Why is this function causing an error?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a function I'm using to get the value of the user's choice of radio button from the html file into my javascript file:

```
  function getRadioCheckedValue(radio_name)
  {
     var oRadio = document.forms[0].elements[radio_name];
     for(var i = 0; i < oRadio.length; i++)
     {
        if(oRadio[i].checked)
       {
           return oRadio[i].value;
        }
     }
     return '';
  }
```

I am using one html file but having two "pages" of radio dials by showing and hiding divs. The two radio dials have different names. When I do the first one, it works fine and retrieves the value correctly, but when I do the second one, the page source underlines the line

```
    for(var i = 0; i < oRadio.length; i++)
```

and says, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

I'm definitely trying to call it by the right name.

When I change the names of the second radio to match the first one in both the html and javascript file, the result is that the value that is pulled is the one pulled the FIRST time (the one from the first "page").

How can I make this function work with a second set of radios?

EDIT: HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Pizza Parlor</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Pizza Parlor</h1>

<!---Beginning of step 1-->
    <span class="step-1">
      <!--step 1 progress bar begin-->
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="min-width: 4em;">
        Step 1/4
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--step 1 progress bar end-->
      <h1>Step 1: Pick your Size</h1>
      <!--step 1 options begin-->
      <form id="size">
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="Small ($10.00)">
            Small (10"): $10.00
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="Medium ($12.00)">
            Medium (12"): $12.00
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="large ($14.00)">
            Large (14"): $14.00
          </label>
        </div>
          <!--step 1 options end-->
        <br>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary"type="submit" class="btn">Next</button>
      </form>
  </span>
  <!--end of step 1-->

<!--step 2 begin-->
  <span class= "step-2">
    <!--step 2 progress bar begin-->
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="min-width: 2em; width: 20%;">
          Step 2 of 4
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--step 2 progress bar end-->
    <h1>Step 2: Pick your Sauce</h1>
    <!--step 2 options begin-->
    <form id="sauce">
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="saucesRadios" id="sauceChoice1" value="Marinara">
          Marinara
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="sauceRadios" id="sauceChoice2" value="Alfredo">
          Alfredo
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="sauceRadios" id="sauceChoice3" value="Pesto">
          Pesto (add $2.00)
        </label>
      </div>
      <!--step 2 options end-->
      <br>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-primary"type="submit" class="btn">Next</button>
    </form>
  </span>
<!--step 2 end -->

<!--step 3 span class begin0-->
  <span class= "step-3">
    <!--step 3 progress bar begin-->
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="min-width: 2em; width: 50%;">
    Step 3 of 4
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--step 3 progress bar end-->
    <form id="toppings">
      <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <h4>Meat</h4>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="optionsToppings" id="optionToppings1" value="pepperoni (+ $2.00)">
          Pepperoni (+ $2.00)
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="optionsToppings" id="optionToppings2" value="sausage (+ $2.00)">
          Sausage (+ $2.00)
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="optionsToppings" id="optionToppings3" value="chicken (+ $3.00)">
          Chicken (+ $3.00)
        </label>
        <br>
        <h4>Veggies</h4>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="optionsToppings" id="optionsToppings5" value="onions (+ $0.25)">
          Onions (+ $0.25)
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="optionsToppings" id="optionsToppings6" value="green peppers (+ $0.25)">
          Green Peppers (+ $0.25)
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="optionsToppings" id="optionsToppings7" value="Jalapeños (+ $0.25)">
          Jalapenos (+ $0.25)
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="optionsToppings" id="optionsToppings8" value="mushrooms (+ $0.25)">
          Mushrooms (+ $0.25)
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="optionsToppings" id="optionsToppings9" value="pineapple (+ $0.50)">
         Pineapple (+ $0.50)
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="optionsToppings" id="optionsToppings10" value="black olives (+ $0.50)">
          Black Olives (+ $0.50)
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="optionsToppings" id="optionsToppings11" value="green olives (+ $0.75)">
          Green Olives (+ $0.75)
        </label>
        <br>
        <h4>Cheese it up!</h4>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="optionsToppings" id="optionsToppings4" value="extra cheese (+ $1.00)">
          Exta Cheese (+ $1.00)
        </label>
      </div>
      <!--step 3 options end-->
      <br>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-primary"type="submit" class="btn">Next</button>
    </form>
  </span>
<!--step 3 span end -->

<span class= "step-4">
  <!--step 4 progress bar begin-->
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="min-width: 2em; width: 75%;">
  Last step!
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--step 4 progress bar end-->
  <form id="how-many">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="number-pizzas">Number of this pizza that you want: </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number-pizzas">
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"type="submit" class="btn">Next</button>
  </form>
  <!--end of form-->
</span>
<!-- step 4 span end-->

<span class= "step-5">
  <em><p> Size: </p></em>
  <ul class="list unstyled" id="crust">
  </ul>
  <em><p> Sauce: </p></em>
  <span class=sauce></span>
  <em><p> Toppings: </p></em>
  <ul class="list unstyled" id="toppings">
  </ul>
  <hr width=25%  align=left>
  <p>Total price of this pizza: $<span class="price"></span></p>
  <p> Number of pies: <span class="num-pizzas"></span></p>
  <p> Total price for this order:</p> <h4>$<span class="total-price"></span></h4>
  <form id="place-order">
    <button class="btn btn-primary"type="submit" class="btn">Submit Order</button>
  </form>
</span>
<!--Step 5 span end-->

<span class="step-6">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;">
  CONGRATULATIONS! Your order is being prepared! Pick it up in about 30 minutes!
    </div>
  </div>
</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

How I'm calling this in javascript:

```
  $(".step-1").show();
  $("form#size").submit(function(event) {
    var pizzaSize = getRadioCheckedValue("optionsRadios");
    $(".my-size").text(pizzaSize);
    $(".step-1").hide();
    $(".step-2").show();
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  $("form#sauce").submit(function(event) {
    var sauce = getRadioCheckedValue("sauceRadios");
    $(".step-2").hide();
    $(".step-3").show();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: Include your HTML, and how you're calling this function

Comment: To answer the question, you are getting this error probably because the oRadio variable is not an array.

Comment: @LeoCHan the error means that `oRadio` is `undefined`, so yes it's not an array :)

Comment: Ok, I have included the HTML and where I call the function in javascript. Why would it work the first time, but not the second? The second time also leaves sauceRadios=Alfredo at the end of the URL bar.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery to get the radios? `$(":radio[name="+radio_name+"]")`?

Comment: Go with Barmar's answer - you're already using jQuery, may as well use it for this too.  One other thing - your first sauce radio appears to have a mistyped name: `saucesRadios`

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll just use the jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript:

```
  function getRadioCheckedValue(radio_name) {
      var group = document.getElementsByName(radio_name);

      for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
          if (group[i].checked == true) {
              return group[i].value;
          }
      }
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/yvdxh8js/

However since you're using jQuery in your OP

jQuery:

```
  function getRadioCheckedValue(radio_name) {
    return $(':radio[name=' + radio_name + ']:checked').val()
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/yvdxh8js/2/

Comment: This fixes the function, thanks, how did you figure that out?

Comment: When you're using put javascript you are returning either nodes or nodelists from the document. node is a single element. nodeList is a collection of elements. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp You were trying to return form.elements from the form which which can not be found by name. They are found by index. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_form_elements.asp

Comment: In regards to the jQuery def review the selectors and pseudo-class selectors. https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with jQuery:

```
var pizzaSize = $(":radio[name=optionsRadios]:checked").val();
```

The reason your code is failing is because you have more than one form on your page: a form for size, another form for sauce, etc. `document.forms[0]` only looks in the first form, so if you try to get a radio button from one of the other forms it won't find it.

Comment: Thank you, using this for my sauceRadios fixed it. I wonder why, even when I use your way to get the pizzaSize, I still can't use sauce = getRadioCheckedValue("sauceRadios"); without breaking it.

Comment: I think the OP will find that this doesn't work either due to problems in the markup.

Comment: @user3169700 look very very closely at the HTML for your "sauce" radio buttons.

Comment: Nah, it was something weird about that function.

Comment: @user3169700 look at the `name` attributes of your "sauce" radio buttons!!

Comment: @Pointy hmm I'm not seeing it

Comment: @user3169700 well the problem isn't exactly what I thought it was, and what's in the code posted here may be different from your actual code, but your "sauce" radio buttons don't all have exactly the same name - one is "saucesRadios", with "sauces" instead of "sauce".

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting that error is that you name **one** of those radio buttons "saucesRadios", but the other two are called "sauceRadios".  Because there's only one radio button with the name you used, you get a single node back and not a node list.

*edit* nope, Barmar's right, you're always only looking at the first form on the page.

Comment: Hmm well maybe not; this could just be a transcription error (which I don't think I'll ever understand).

Comment: Oh, I was posting in between changing stuff around, fixing that doesn't fix the function issue, though Sean Wessell's did